# mysql get table column names in alphabetical order

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

Is it possible to query a MySQL database to get the column names of a table in alphabetical order? I know that

```
SHOW COLUMNS `table_name`;
```

or

```
DESCRIBE `table_name`;
```

will give me a list of the columns in a table (along with other info), but is it possible to alter the query in order to get the columns sorted alphabetically. Adding ORDER BY 'Field' didn't work, it gave a syntax error.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The ANSI [INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables (in this case, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) provide more flexibility in MySQL:

```
SELECT c.column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
 WHERE c.table_name = 'tbl_name'
-- AND c.table_schema = 'db_name'    
ORDER BY c.column_name
```

Comment: Worked great, would use again. Can you tell me why the c.table_schema condition is there though because it seemed to work without it.

Comment: @John Scipione: The double dash "--" is a comment in SQL; the table_schema is commented out from the query.  Remove the double dash for it to be evaluated in the statement.

Comment: Works like a charm! I also used a group by column name also.

Answer (score 4):

Every field was listed twice until I used `group by column name`

```
 select c.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
 where c.TABLE_NAME = `'tbl_name'` 
 group by c.column_name 
 order by c.column_name
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want more details, below query is really handy:

```
   SELECT COLUMN_NAME  as 'Field',
   COLUMN_TYPE    as 'Type',
   IS_NULLABLE    as 'Null',
   COLUMN_KEY     as 'Key',
   COLUMN_DEFAULT as 'Default',
   EXTRA          as 'Extra'
   from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
   where TABLE_NAME   = 'my table' and
   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my database'
   add ordering
   order by Type;  --
```